# Tensorflow has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I am using NN module, version 0.0.9, tensorflow 1.13.1 and python 3.6. I am having a trouble loading the nn module because "from tensorflow import *" fails. The stack trace is givven under. Thanks for any help.

```
File "./train.py", line 9, in <module>
   import nn
File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nn/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
   from . import tf
File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nn/tf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow import *
          AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: Do you have a file called tensorflow.py ?

Comment: import tensorflow as tf works but it fails on from tensorflow import *

Answer (score 0):

### Version issue: Install tensorflow==1.0.0 and python3.5

According to this [post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27127#issuecomment-479982171) you have an version problem. Try downgrading your tensorflow version to 1.0.0 and python version to 3.5... or use new virtual environment.